# VMWare Player - executing a command on Guest from Host

Tags: linux, vmware

I'm running a linux server on VMWare Player. Host's operating system is Windows7. Is it possible to execute a command from command line (on Host) which will run on the Guest?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible. You can use telnet to connect with Windows (Professional and above) guest system and telnet or ssh with *nix guests. So as you are running linux as guest, the best option for you is ssh (use putty - it is quite powerful implementation).